# How to change gridview row color by cell value?

Tags: c#, devexpress, datarow

I have cell name "MY_CELL"
I want to create if "MY_CELL" value is OK! then that Row color will be changed with GreenYellow.

```
    private void gridView2_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
{
if (gridView2.RowCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gridView2.DataRowCount; i++)
                {

                     string text_sms2 = gridView2.GetRowCellValue(i, "MY_CELL").ToString();                

                     if (text_sms2.Contains("ok"))
                    { 
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

These code seems like works but all my rows color changed with "GreenYellow".

Comment: What is`e` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the loop, since RowStyle event is raised for each individial row. Your code is setting apperence for each row according to the value in the last one.

Try this:

```
private void gridView2_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) {

  if (e.RowHandle >= 0) {
    e.HighPriority = true;
    var text = gridView2.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, view.Columns["MY_CELL"]);

    if(text.Contains("ok") { // mind case sensitivity!!!
      e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
    }            
    else {
      e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I got these errors:

Error 106 does not contain a definition for `HighPriority` ...
Error 107 no extenstion method GetRowCellDisplayText ...
Error 108 view.Columns["MY_CELL"]) cannot convert  from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Which version of DX are you using? Which properties are in `e`?

Comment: Maybe it's time to upgrade, since the current version is 20. Remove line 106 (`HighPriority`) and change 107 to `var text = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "MY_CELL").ToString();`